# Making a custom scale_color_gradient but assigning number values to the colors

Tags: r, colors, gradient, scale-color-manual

I'm having trouble getting a custom color gradient to work. I want to assign certain colors to certain values but have the colors flow. This is what I've got so far.

```
thi_color_scale<-scale_color_gradientn(
  colors = c("#660000", "#cc0000", "#e69f00", "#9a9a9a"),
  values = c(0, 2.9, #critically low
             3, 5, #low
             5, 8, #int
             8, max(data$avg_total_egg_thi)))#high

iso_egg_plot_thi_conc<- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = d13c_lc, y = d15n, shape = egg_thi_status, color = avg_total_egg_thi)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.75, stroke = 1) +
  
  # Use the custom color gradient scale
  thi_color_scale
iso_egg_plot_thi_conc
```

plot
[image]

I've tried finding the middle value of each of these ranges for the colors and just setting those as the number assigned to the color but that just spits out a grey plot.

Comment: hi axc! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Your question will get answered 10x faster if you include data in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `scale_color_gradientn`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) says:

> values
>
> *if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the colours vector. **See rescale() for a convenience function to map an arbitrary range to between 0 and 1.***

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = qsec)) +
  geom_point(size = 15) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("#660000", "#cc0000", "#e69f00", "#9a9a9a"), 
                        values = scales::rescale(c(0, 2.9, 3, 5, 8, max(mtcars$qsec)))) # duplicates can be removed by us, because they will be removed by ggplot later anyway
```

[image: plot]